# Google Analytics Shopping Behavior gtag Product View not working

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, google-tag-manager, gtag.js

I have a Ecommerce platform and I am trying to set it up to report the way I want in Google Analytics's E-commerce Shopping Behavior...

I have the Add to Cart gtag working just fine, and reporting well in 'Shopping Behavior':

```
gtag('event', 'add_to_cart', {
    "content_type": "product",
    "items": [
    {
        "id": car_class,
        "name": car_class,
        "variant": coveragec,
        "price": carpricetotalnum
    }
    ]
});
```

The issue I am having is getting the Product Views to work... I have this tag in there:

```
gtag('event', 'select_content', {
        "content_type": "product",
    });
```

And it's firing, but is is not showing as a Product View in 'Shopping Behavior'

Can someone tel me how to properly set this up?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `view_item` event to report Product Detail Views as shopping behaviour. `select_content` are to be reported as Product Clicks within ecommerce reports.
Check the list of all the supported events in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/enhanced-ecommerce#product_and_promotion_actions).